# LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks causes BufferOverflow

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I've created an interface to get contacts. Here is the codeL:

```
public class ContactLoader implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>

        {


            MainActivity mContext;

            public static final String QUERY_KEY = "query";

            public static final String TAG = "Meldung:";


            ArrayList<contact> ContactList;

            public ContactLoader(MainActivity context) {
                mContext = context;
            }

            @Override
            public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loaderindex, Bundle args)
            {
                String query = args.getString(QUERY_KEY);
                Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Contactables.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, query);
                // END_INCLUDE(uri_with_query)


                // BEGIN_INCLUDE(cursor_loader)
                // Easy way to limit the query to contacts with phone numbers.
                String selection =
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Contactables.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " = " + 1;

                // Sort results such that rows for the same contact stay together.
                String sortBy = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Contactables.LOOKUP_KEY;

                /*return new CursorLoader(
                        mContext,  // Context
                        uri,       // URI representing the table/resource to be queried
                        null,      // projection - the list of columns to return.  Null means "all"
                        selection, // selection - Which rows to return (condition rows must match)
                        null,      // selection args - can be provided separately and subbed into selection.
                        sortBy);   // string specifying sort order
                */
                return new CursorLoader(
                        mContext,
                        uri,
                        null,
                        selection,
                        null,
                        sortBy
                );
            }




            @Override
            public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {


                if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
                    return;
                }

                // Pulling the relevant value from the cursor requires knowing the column index to pull
                // it from.
                // BEGIN_INCLUDE(get_columns)
                int phoneColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
                int emailColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS);
                int nameColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Contactables.DISPLAY_NAME);
                int lookupColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Contactables.LOOKUP_KEY);
                int typeColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Contactables.MIMETYPE);

                int PhotoID = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Contactables.PHOTO_ID);
                // END_INCLUDE(get_columns)

                cursor.moveToFirst();
                // Lookup key is the easiest way to verify a row of data is for the same
                // contact as the previous row.
                String lookupKey = "";


                do {
                    // BEGIN_INCLUDE(lookup_key)
                    String currentLookupKey = cursor.getString(lookupColumnIndex);


                    contact newContact = new contact();
                    if (!lookupKey.equals(currentLookupKey)) {


                        String extractedName = cursor.getString(nameColumnIndex);
                        newContact.setName(extractedName);
                        lookupKey = currentLookupKey;
                    }
                    // END_INCLUDE(lookup_key)

                    // BEGIN_INCLUDE(retrieve_data)
                    // The data type can be determined using the mime type column.

                    try {
                        String mimeType = cursor.getString(typeColumnIndex);
                        if (mimeType.equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)) {

                            //Funktioncall fuer Nachricht und Anruf suchen

                            String _phoneNumber = cursor.getString(phoneColumnIndex);

                            newContact.addCallAction(new phoneCallContactAction(_phoneNumber, mContext));
                            newContact.addMessageAction(new sendSMSContactAction(_phoneNumber, mContext));


                        } else if (mimeType.equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)) {


                            String _adress = cursor.getString(emailColumnIndex);

                            newContact.addMessageAction(new sendEmailcontactAction(_adress));


                        } else if (!cursor.getString(PhotoID).equals(null)) {


                        }

                        mContext.addContact(newContact);


                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Log.d(TAG, "fail");
                    }
                    // END_INCLUDE(retrieve_data)

                    // Look at DDMS to see all the columns returned by a query to Contactables.
                    // Behold, the firehose!
                    for(String column : cursor.getColumnNames()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, column + column + ": " +
                                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(column)) + "\n");
                    }
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());



            }





            @Override
            public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {

            }


        }
```

The code causes a buffer overflow: logcat shows this:

> onFatalError, processing error from engine(4)
>                                                                                                 com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.a.g: Error reading from
>   input stream
>                                                                                                     at
>   com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.i.a.a(SourceFile:342)
>                                                                                                     at
>   com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.i.a$1.run(SourceFile:1367)
>                                                                                                     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
>                                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                                                     at
>   com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:66)
>                                                                                                     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>                                                                                                     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>                                                                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
>                                                                                                     at
>   com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ad$1.run(SourceFile:85)
>                                                                                                  Caused by:
>   com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error
>   code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.Tee.g(SourceFile:2531)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ap.read(SourceFile:555)
>                                                                                                     at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.al.run(SourceFile:362)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ak$1.run(SourceFile:471)
>                                                                                                     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
>                                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                                                     at
>   com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:66)
>                                                                                                     at
>   com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:139)
>                                                                                                     at
>   com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:139)
>                                                                                                     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
>                                                                                                     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
>                                                                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
>                                                                                                     at
>   com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ad$1.run(SourceFile:85)

the Contact class just represents the data. Previous tests show no problems, as the class is really simple there shouldn't be any problems with butteroverflows.

MainActivity has a getContact function which add the contact to the interface. There I dont see any possible mistakes.

Do you any idea?